# Jupyter get stuck in docker container

Tags: docker, jupyter-lab

I have created a jupyter_lab docker and usually it works quite fine but sometimes it get stuck. Usually i could never reproduce this problem but now, apparently he totally doesn't like this file (https://hgdownload.soe.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/mm39/bigZips/genes/refGene.gtf.gz). Using R, once I

```
gtf=read.table("refGene.gtf",header=TRUE,sep="\t")
```

it looks like everything is loaded fine but if in another cell I call for

```
print(gtf)
```

it just get stuck there. And the weird thing is that it get stuck even if instead of printing the gtf variable I ask him to print any other thing. Also if I put together in the same cell

gtf=read.table("refGene.gtf",header=TRUE,sep="\t")
print(gtf)

It works properly but then i cannot use anymore the other cells.
If i exec a /bin/bash into the same opened docker that has the stuck jupyterlab and I open R with the terminal and perform the same tasks I dont have any problem, so looks like is a cell jupyter lab problem.

Comment: Is this particular `gtf` file particularly large? From what you describe it simple sounds like a memory problem. Jupyter has more overhead and that is why you don't see it in your terminal. Since you post boils down to no specific question, it would probably be best posted at [the Jupyter Discourse Forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org/) as that site is more suited to discussion and exchanges of ideas. If you do end up posting there, please note the cross-post in both places so that responders aren't duplicating responses & so that other following up later can follow along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. @lckr/jupyterlab_variableinspector slow everything down with big data. Just remove this and everything will work again.